# Getting error "XPath is invalid" for "hours-from-duration($duration)"

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I need help with one of my issues. I am new to XSLT. Right now I am trying to write an XSLT which will generate text output (example: "01:30").
In my XSLT 2.0, I am calling the XPath function `hours-from-duration($duration)` and this function is throwing the error

> XPath is invalid

I can also see the above error in the following logs. Please help me with my issues. Thanks...

> 16:01:39,403 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(hours-from-duration, [variable-ref(duration/node-set)])'.
>
> 16:01:39,404 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Could not compile stylesheet
>
> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:858) at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:648)

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" 
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    version="1.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="request" select="/*[local-name()='Payout']/*[local-name()='Request']" />
    <xsl:variable name="duration" select="$request/Time" />
        
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="(hours-from-duration($duration))"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="(minutes-from-duration($duration))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Input:

```
<Payout>
 <Request Commit="true" Transaction="false">
  <Month>JAN</Month>
  <Time>P01H30M33S</Time>
 </Request>
</Payout>
```

Comment: Where is `$duration` set?

Answer (score 1):

Your duration value is invalid. It is missing a "T". It should be `PT01H30M33S`.

Answer (score 1):

hours-from-duration() is an XPath 2.0 function. You are using Xalan, which only supports XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0.

Furthermore, these functions expect an object of type `xs:duration`. You are passing it a node (a Time element). If you switch to an XSLT 2.0 processor, you will need either (a) to make sure the processor is schema-aware and Time is validated as an xs:duration, or (b) to convert it to type `xs:duration` explicitly, by calling `xs:duration(Time)`.

And of course you will need to make sure it's a valid duration as pointed out by @MadsHansen

Comment: Thanks for your input.......I Just ran the below code and its giving different error messages in logs (Note: I added T in the request XML PT01H30M33S) :
- Could you please review my code and let me where am doing mistake.
- To switch to XSLT2.0 processor what I need to do.

Comment: I have added the latest xsl above in my comment section. Plz have a look. Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, I thought I explained. Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor. It doesn't understand XSLT 2.0. To run XSLT 2.0 from Java, use Saxon instead.

Comment: @ani The StackOverflow convention is not to write comments saying "thanks", but to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark which you see next to the answer.